# How do you send hotkeys in coded workflow of uiPath in C#?

Tags: uipath

I am trying to copy data displayed in a grid of a desktop application. When done manually, I can do Control + C on the grid to copy all the data displayed and then paste it on Excel spreadsheet using control + V.

I need to perform the same on coded workflow of uiPath.

I have identified the element i am dealing with.

```
var screen = uiAutomation.Attach(Descriptors.FidessaTool.FoundOrdersWindow);
screen.click("myGrid");
// want to perform Ctrl C here*
```

Comment: What is the question? Just do it in Studio. Or do you need it in Code?